# minimum of $\frac{1}{2}x^tQx-c^tx$ subject to $Ax=b$ is local $\iff$ is global

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

> $$\min \frac{1}{2}x^tQx-c^tx\\ Ax=b$$ where $Q\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times
>  n}$ is symmetric, $c\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $A\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$
>   and $b\in\mathbb{R}^m$. Prove that if ${x}^*$ is a local
>   minimizer $\iff$ it is a global minimizer

We can transform the problem with constraints to a problem without constraints by doing

$$\phi(\gamma) = f(\overline{x} + Z\gamma)$$

where $f=\frac{1}{2}x^tQx-c^T x$, $\overline{x}$ is a solution of $Ax=b$ and $Z$ is a matrix elements from the basis of $\ker A$ as columns. Then the problem is transformed into minimizing the unconstrained problem $\min \phi(\gamma)$.

Global minimizer implies local, now,

If $\overline{x}$ is a local minimizer, it means $\nabla \phi(\gamma^*) = Z^T\nabla f(x^*)=0$ (I think), and $\nabla^2 \phi(\gamma)=Z^t\nabla^2 f(x^*)Z\ge 0$ (I think).

I'm thinking about what can be used now. Does somebody have an idea or can find some error in my thinking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out, the problem is equivalent to:
$$
\begin{align}
\phi(y) = f(\overline{x} + Zy) &= (\overline{x} + Zy)^TQ(\overline{x} + Zy) - c^T(\overline{x} + Zy) \\
& = y^T(Z^TQZ)y + (2Z^TQ\overline{x} + c)^Ty + \alpha
\end{align}
$$
for some constant $\alpha$ (whose value is irrelevant for the optimal $y$). If an optimum exists, the matrix $Z^TQZ$ must be positive semidefinite, and $\phi$ must therefore be convex. For a convex function, any local optimum is also a global optimum.

Comment: If an optimum exists for $\phi$ then the matrix $Z^TQZ$ must be positive semidefinite because $\nabla^2 \phi = Z^TQZ$. You're using the necessary second order condition for a minimum, right? I don't understand why you can use such condition, because I think the exercise is talking about a minimum with restrictions, and you use a criteria for minimum without restrictions

Comment: Ok, I've notes that for minimum with restrictions, one of the necessary conditions is that $Z^T\nabla^2 fZ\ge 0$ so this part is ok, and the part about $\phi$ being convex also. Now, it's true that for convex functions, a local optimum without restrictions is a global one, but what about local optimum with restrictions?

Comment: @Paprika $\phi$ is an unconstrained function

Comment: @Paprika did this satisfactorily answer your question?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the delay accepting it